# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am echoing some data from the PHP side along with a tag and here is the code

```
 echo '<a class="ui label" onclick="variant_desc('.$product_id.');"> '.$variant->Field1.' </a>';
```

Now the function that I have mentioned within the tag, when I click it throws me the

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

error... BUT WHY? Where am I masking mistake?

Comment: how does that PHP code render in HTML?  Have you verified `$product_id` and `$variant->Field1` return what you're expecting?

Comment: yes...in my response section of network tab in inspect element...it showing me the whole tag..the html tag is also displayed on the page...if I remove the id, the function is also called. only part is there is some error with concatenation ..and I dont knw what is that

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's caused of nested quotations. Try this instead:

```
echo '<a class=\"ui label\" onclick=\"variant_desc(\'.$product_id.\');\"> \'.$variant->Field1.\' </a>';
```

Comment: nope..its returning `'.$variant->Field1.' '.$variant->Field1.'` this